# Catch asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError on both python 3.8 and python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm using asyncio with websockets, and I need to do something when the socket is closed or timed out:

```
try:
    async for msg in ws:
        if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
            print(msg)
except concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError:
    print("Cancelled")
    pass
except (concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError, asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError):
    print("Timedout")
    pass
```

I need this code to run on both Python 3.6 and 3.8, but `asyncio.exceptions` is not defined in Python 3.6.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use an identifier that begins with an underscore, such as `_base`, you are almost certainly making a mistake - even if those names happen to work now, they are internal to the implementation and can change without notice.

> What should I do?

A good course of action is to look up the public name in the documentation. For example, googling asyncio timeouterror leads to [`asyncio.TimeoutError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.TimeoutError) public name. Likewise, `CancelledError` is exposed by asyncio as [`asyncio.CancelledError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.CancelledError) - the fact that it is taken from the same exception in `concurrent.futures` is just an implementation detail.